# Is there a way to easily escape or modify certain characters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, api, unicode, rss

Currently, my rss script generates a rss feed for a website using an API. It worked until I forgot that some special characters aren't allowed in xml format. What is the best way to get rid of or escape the & symbol?

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import os


def generate_rss(data):
    rss = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
<title>ComicK - RSS Feed</title>
<link>https://github.com/ld3z/manga-rss</link>
<description>A simple RSS feed for ComicK!</description>
"""

    for i in data:
        c = i["md_comics"]

        rss += """\
<item>
    <title>{}</title>
    <link>{}</link>
    <description>{}</description>
</item>
""".format(
            f"{c['title']} - Chapter {i['chap']}",
            f"https://comick.app/comic/{c['slug']}",
            f"Chapter {i['chap']} of {c['title']} is now available on ComicK!",
        )

    rss += "\n</channel>\n</rss>"
    return rss


url = "https://api.comick.app/chapter/?lang=en&page=1&order=new&accept_mature_content=true"
data = requests.get(url).json()

filename = f"./comick/comick-rss-nsfw.xml"

os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)

with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
    print(generate_rss(data), file=f_out)
```

I think it would have to be put into a list, but then I am not entirely sure if it would still be the same.

Comment: Don't create XML by hand, use a library. It will do all the necessary escaping.

Comment: Something like feedgen?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-xml-documents-using-python/